# Tensorflow M2 Pro Failure

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

When I run the following test script for tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    classes=100,)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=4)
```

I obtain the following terminal output:

```
Metal device set to: Apple M2 Pro

systemMemory: 16.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 5.33 GB

2023-03-23 00:26:32.203361: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2023-03-23 00:26:32.203521: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
zsh: bus error  python3 app/model/tf_verify.py
```

Comment: How did you installed Tensorflow?

Comment: python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.9.0 tensorflow-metal==0.6.0 --force-reinstall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While unclear from the official Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/), it looks like the `tensorflow-macos` version should match the `tensorflow-metal` plugin version from the "Releases" section. Since you are using `tensorflow-macos==2.9`, you should use `tensorflow-metal==0.5.0` and not `tensorflow-metal==0.6.0`.

I was able to reproduce and solve the issue on a MacBook Pro M1 Pro and the training works fine.